# How to put the same JLabel twice

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jlabel

I'm trying to create a "gif" with JFrame and JPanel and I have a problem looping the "gif".
This is the part of the code that does the "gif":

```
    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("main");
    mainFrame.setSize(newWidth, newHeight);
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
            mainFrame.add(labels[i]);
            mainFrame.setVisible(true);
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(delay);
            mainFrame.remove(labels[i]);
        }
```

It runs only once but when I debug it shows that it keeps running

Comment: maybe I have bad day, but not understand

Comment: The title and question seem completely unrelated. Also, why should this run more than once? The loop is run once and after it added and removed all labels it terminates. 
If you want it to run indefinitely, surround the loop with while(true){} or even better while(notTerminated){}, so you can set notTerminated to false e.g. by hitting a button...

Comment: First of all you cannot using `sleep()` in Swing app. If you want to provide a delay, you should use `javax.swing.Tmer`. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more info. Second: you cannot place one Swing component twice. If you add a Swing component second time it will be removed from the place where it was added at first time. If you still need help, please provide a runnable example ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org)), so we also can reproduce your problem and debug the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add

```
mainFrame.revalidate();
mainFrame.repaint();
```

after

```
mainFrame.add(labels[i]);
```

and after

```
mainFrame.remove(labels[i]);
```

Also, I would like to recommend you to read about [Event Dispatcher Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).